# Count items inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

So i have an array full of random things (lets say fruits)

```
$fruit = array ("Banana", "Strawberry", "Apple",);
```

which is followed by a

```
echo implode (glue ' and ', $fruit);
```

which is supposed to list every single fruit that appears in the array

Now, how do I count the amount of items that appear wihtin in the list? As in how do i make the code show that it's 3 items

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: use count - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: I have to wonder how much research you did on this

Comment: `echo implode (glue ' and ', $fruit);` doesn't give you a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count()` method of php.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/de/function.count.php)

For showing the amount you can use it like that:

```
echo "Amount: " . count($fruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Count().

```
$fruit = array ("Banana", "Strawberry", "Apple",);

echo implode(' and ', $fruit) . " is " . count($fruit) . " fruits";
// Banana and Strawberry and Apple is 3 fruits
```

https://3v4l.org/19LqD